# Remove Arial and Helvetica fonts from Summernote

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, summernote

I'm trying to use only Roboto, but [Summernote](https://summernote.org/) adds to this Arial and Helvetica. Is there a way to remove them?

[image]

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    'summernote': {

        # As an example, using Summernote Air-mode
        'airMode': False,

        # Change editor size
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '480',

        'fontNames': ['Roboto Light', 'Roboto Regular', 'Roboto Bold'],
        'fontNamesIgnoreCheck': ['Roboto Light', 'Roboto Regular', 'Roboto Bold'],

        'toolbar': [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['fontname', ['fontname']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['height', ['height']],
            ['table', ['table']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
            ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
            ['help', ['help']]
        ],

        'styleTags': ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'small'],


    },

}
```

I am using [Django-Summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote).

Answer (score 1):

Set in your css file the font-family that you want. (default).

Or add in the html. example:

```html
 <style>
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto Light"
    }
 </style>
```

And `SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG` will work.

Comment: Where is this css place, which file exactly ?